# Heat Map using MapBox iOS SDK and colorize-alpha

Tags: ios, mapbox

Is the colorize-alpha method (aka: poor man's heatmap) specified here - https://www.mapbox.com/blog/colorize-alpha-image-filter/ - able to be used within the MapBox iOS SDK - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/ - or is this only for web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of functionality isn't available in the MapBox iOS API, but unlike web, there are a lot of this sort of graphics capabilities in the base Cocoa/UIKit frameworks. Specifically check out [this blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/ios-hatched-shapes/) for an example of colorizing imagery on the fly. It's not exactly a heat map, but if you produced a grayscale heat map like in Artem's post, you could color it in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try LFHeatMaps to generate a similar effect: https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap